# code blocks power function is not working in c

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

i am using code block for learning c. my code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  int x;
  x = pow(5,2);
  printf("%d", x);
}

Output is 25
```

When i am using this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  int x,i,j;
  printf("please enter first value");
  scanf("%d", &i);//5
  printf("please enter second value");//2
  scanf("%d", &j);
  x = pow(i,j);
  printf("%d", x);
}

Output is 24
```

what is wrong here? i am just taking value using scan function and also using pow function in a same way.

Comment: works for me, but you should return 0 at the end of your main method

Comment: Have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) - pow's prototype is `double pow(double x, double y);`.  Start by using the proper types.

Comment: @fvu If he asks for integer values, and he wants to have an integer result, why are the types "inproper" then?

Comment: You should pick between C or C++, not both. Otherwise you get confusing comments and answers, such as "you forgot to return 0", which doesn't apply to C++. As it currently stands, this is a C question.

Comment: @junix because whatever type you slap in front of it, pow **will** return a double initially - and as double --> int conversion is just truncation some oddity in OP's platform CAN cause 5^2 be 24.99999 which as an int is 24.

Comment: Given the use of printf, scanf and including of ".h" files, I'd say this is C, not C++.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you have a naive implementation of `pow` in your `libm` (I get 25, as it should be). If that computes `pow(x,y)` as `exp(y*log(x))` for positive `x` without checking for (small) integral exponents and treating them specially, you get

```
Prelude> 2 * log 5
3.2188758248682006
Prelude> exp it
24.999999999999996
```

a `double` result slightly smaller than 25, so when that is converted to `int` it is truncated to 24.

To check, assign the result of `pow(i,j)` to a `double` and print that out.

With hardcoded `pow(5,2)`, the compiler (most likely, it's what gcc does even without optimisation) computes the result during compilation exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing initialization to this:

```
int x=-1 ,i=-1 ,j=-1;
```

And last print to this:

```
printf("pow(%d, %d) == %d\n", i, j, x);
```

That should give good hint about the problem. Also, check return values of `scanf`, they should return number of items read, ie. 1 with code above.

It's almost certain, that you entered invalid input for scanf, and `i` or `j` were left uninitialized, and that 24 is just garbage value.

Also, compile with warnings enabled, and fix them (like, add `return 0;` to end of `main`).

Comment: Or learn to use a debugger and inspect the variables after scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Your code correctly gives 25 on my windows x64.

You probably needs to run it again see if you just read it wrong...
The missing "return 0;" is not the problem here.

If, anything, could ever go wrong,
you can try adding

```
fflush(stdin);//or out
```

after very scanf and printf.
If any of the flushes solves your problem, you know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is nothing wrong with the second program, except that you must add at the end

```
return 0;
```

If you read the value j with 2 then the result will be just 25.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code i got result 25 which is correct.
Although Try changing the data type of result such as float or double.