# sieve of eratosthenes in c

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Here is my code for sieve of eratosthenes in C.
It is giving me the following output.

2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
25
31
35
37
41
43
47

My output include 25 and 35 also which are not prime numbers and it doesn't include 29.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int i,a[50],b[50],j,n=0,s;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
        a[i] = 1;
    a[0]=a[1] = 0;

    for(i=2;i<50;i++)
        if(a[i])
            for(j=pow(i,2);j<50;j+=i)
                a[j] = 0;

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
        if(a[i])
        {
            b[n] = i;
            n++;
        }

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d\n",b[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe you have different implementation of `pow()`. Try `i*i` instead.

Comment: The same for me. Please specify compiler version and more environment details.

Comment: And compile without optimization flags (if gcc)

Comment: please specify the compiler

Comment: Are you using Turbo C by any chance?

Comment: No, i'm using Code Blocks.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would recommend using more descriptive variable names than `a` and `b`.

Comment: @user1178323: CodeBlocks is not a compiler; it is just a front end to a compiler you choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiled with gcc version 4.4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-2ubuntu1) your code returnes correct result. The issue is probably related to a compiler and to the `pow()` implementation.

Probably you have a naive implementation of `pow` that computes `pow(x,y)` as `exp(y*log(x))`. This is *floating point arithmetic* and it suffers from common floating point issues. This imply that result of `pow(x,y)` converted to integer will be truncated, because of double arithmetic `log(x)*y` and exponentiation that will return double value slightly smaller than integer `x*y`.

Change the code to

```
for( j = i * i; j < 50; j += i)
    a[j] = 0;
```

Additionally, we can iterate only until sqrt(n) because the second loop will only then be executed:

```
for( i = 2; i < sqrt(50); i++)
    if( a[i]) // if not marked
        /* mark starting from i*i because i*j for j<i
         * has been already marked when i was j */
        for( j = i * i; j < 50; j += i)
            a[j] = 0;
```

related issue: [code blocks power function is not working in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15050997/1141471)

Comment: `2*i` has already been marked as non prime when `i` was `2`. Similarly for `3*i`, `4*i`, etc. It is sufficient to start at `i*i`.

Comment: @bits_international Still this is no answer to SO problem. In fact we're dealing with some others issues than algorithmic ones.

Comment: Yeah, the pow implementation of code blocks was the problem. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I am at your service, my good sir

Answer (score 4):

As others have observed, the error is in the `pow` function. I cannot reproduce your error with the code you've shown, but when I roll my own `ppow` function:

```
double ppow(double a, double x)
{
    return exp(log(a) * x);
}
```

my list matches yours. I think standard-conforming implementations of `pow` should treat integer exponents as a special case that can take negative bases, so your `pow` seems to be non-conforming.

Instead of `pow(i, 2)`, use `i*i`. That should be faster and you won't have to link to the maths library either.

Comment: Thank you, using i*i instead of pow(i,2) solved my problem but I can't still understand why pow(i,2) is giving me the wrong answer.

Comment: `pow` works with floating-point numbers. They are not exact, even less so when they are the result of a calculation as in the `ppow` implementaion above. For `ppow(20, 2)` I get 399.9999999999999, for exmple, which upon conversion to int will become 399. You could probably get away with rounding: `ppow(i, 2) + 0.5`, but I recommend to use simple multiplication for integer powers, especially for simple ones like squares.

Comment: What is the difference between ppow() and pow().

Comment: `pow` is the power function of your maths library. `ppow` is the implementation of `pow` I used above. It is not a standard-conforming implementation, but I assume that the math library you use implements `pow` that way. I used `ppow` to show that your compiler's `pow` is probably broken.

Answer (score 2):

I try to reproduce your output, but I can't.

OS info:

> $ uname -a Linux 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4
> 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Compiler info:

> $ gcc --version gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Compile:

> $ gcc sieve_of_eratosthenes.c -lm -o sieve_of_eratosthenes

Launch:

> $ ./sieve_of_eratosthenes
>
> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47

Comment: Should be a comment, though.

Comment: My rate doesn't allow me leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When the `pow` function makes use of the floating-point unit on your processor, it might yield an exception.

When such exception occurs during the execution of this function, it might return an incorrect value.

This is probably the case on your system when you call `pow(i,2)` with `i` being equal to `5`.

As a circumstantial evidence to support this conjecture, please note that every number (in the specified range of [0-49]) which is a multiple of **5 and a prime larger than 5**, appears on your list of prime numbers.

---

Here is a piece of code for retrieving the exceptions that may have occurred as a result of a FP operation:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_fe_exceptions()
{
    printf("Exceptions raised:");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)) printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT  )) printf(" FE_INEXACT  ");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID  )) printf(" FE_INVALID  ");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW )) printf(" FE_OVERFLOW ");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW)) printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

And here is the description of each exception:

```
FE_DIVBYZERO // Pole error occurred in an earlier floating-point operation
FE_INEXACT   // Inexact result: rounding was necessary to store the result of an earlier floating-point operation
FE_INVALID   // Domain error occurred in an earlier floating-point operation
FE_OVERFLOW  // The result of an earlier floating-point operation was too large to be representable
FE_UNDERFLOW // The result of an earlier floating-point operation was subnormal with a loss of precision
```